# Confused about Continuous Random variable

Tags: probability

Hello I have just begun learning about continuous random variables, and I am already confused on the first example given.

I know that the probability distribution function of a random variable X, is given by $$F(x)=P(X \le x)$$ $$x \in \mathbb{R}$$

The example given is,

Suppose that X is the number that results when we roll an unfair die that has probabilities $P(x=1)=.2$

$P(x=2)=.1 $

$P(x=3)=.2 $

$P(x=4)=.1 $

$P(x=5)=.2$

$P(x=6)=.2$

Then find the probability distribution function.

It then gives the solution]

$F(x)= 0$ if $-\infty \lt x \lt 1$

$=.2$ if $1 \le x \lt 2$

$=.3$ if $2 \le x \lt 3$

$= .5$ if $3 \le x \lt 4$

$=.6$ if $4 \le x \lt 5$

$=.8$ if  $5 \le x \lt 6$

$=1$ if $6 \le x \lt \infty$

But this is so confusing to me. I mean I of course see what is happening, in that they are adding the probabilities.

But lets take for example $F(x)=.5$ if $3 \le x \lt 4$

How is this .5? isnt the probability that X is less than 4 and greater or equal to 3 just the probability that x is 3? What is the .5?

and isnt the probability that x is greater than or equal to 2 , but less than 3 just equal to the probability that x is 2?

I am really confused, hopefully someone understands what I am trying to ask.

Thanks

Comment: That answer appears to be the cumulative density function, not the probability density function.

Comment: For $3\leq x<4$ $F(x)$ does not denote the probability that $X$ is less than $4$ and $\geq3$. It denotes the probability that $X$ is less than $x$. So $F(x)=P(X\leq x)=P(X=1\vee X=2\vee X=3)=P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)$.

Comment: Thanks so then what is the reason we write x greater than

Comment: I mean if it does not denote the Probability between those values, then what does the $3 \le x \lt 4$ signify?

Comment: The random variable is *discrete* (not continuous), so $F(x)=P(X\le x)$ changes (increases) only at values of $x\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$, which are the only points with nonzero probability. In the intervals between these points, $P(X\le x)$ is  constant (a different constant for each interval).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is this $.5$? isnt the probability that $X$ is less than $4$ and greater or equal to $3$ just the probability that $x$ is $3$? What is the $.5$?

You're forgetting that $F(x)$ is supposed to be $\Pr(X\le x)$.  What they're saying is that if $3\le x<4$ then $\Pr(X\le x) = 0.5$. This is not supposed to be the probability that $3\le X < 4$; it's supposed to be the probability that $X\le x$ if $3\le x<4$.

For example, if $x=3.574$, then $3\le x < 4$.  So this is saying $P(X\le 3.574) = 0.5$.  In fact $\Pr(X\le 3.574)$ is $\Pr(X=1\text{ or }X=2\text{ or }X=3)$.

Answer (score 0):

For $3\le x<4$, using that $X$ takes its values on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ (almost surely), we have
$$F(x)=P(X<x)=P(X\le 3)=P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)\,.$$

Comment: Then what here is significnance of bounding x

Comment: @Quality -  Be sure to distinguish between the random variable $X$ and its possible values $x$. The "bounding" notation $3 \le x \lt 4$ is just identifying one of the intervals of possible values in which the probability $P(X\le x)$ is a constant (specific to that interval).  (Also, see my comment to you your question.)